# Getting query string parameters from API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using Amazon API Gateway to invoke a lambda function. I am testing a get request with the following as my query string `earlyDate="12-01-21"&laterDate="12-03-21"`.

I currently have my lambda function returning the event that gets passed:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(event)
    }
```

This works as expected. When I test my API gateway I get a response which includes

```
"queryStringParameters": {
    "earlyDate": "12-01-21",
    "laterDate": "12-03-21"
  },
  "multiValueQueryStringParameters": {
    "earlyDate": [
      "12-01-21"
    ],
    "laterDate": [
      "12-03-21"
    ]
  },
```

This indicates I should be able to access these query parameters at `event.queryStringParameters`.  However when I change my lambda function to return those:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(event.queryStringParameters)
    }
```

The result is a 502 error.

How do I access the query string parameters passed in from my API Gateway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, event is a dict and we can access its query params as `event['queryStringParameters']`

We can confirm that by

```
for key, value in event.items():
   print(key, value)
```

Lambda could return this:

```
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps(event['queryStringParameters'])
}
```